# Run raw SQL statement inside my .NET core console application and map the results to C# variables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core

I have the following SQL statement to get data from multiple tables inside my SQL Server database:

```
SELECT max(ad.ORG_NAME) AS "Account", wo.WORKORDERID AS "Request ID", max(aau.FIRST_NAME) AS "Requester", max(aci.emailid) "Email ID",max(wo.TITLE) AS "Request Title", max(ti.FIRST_NAME) AS "Technician", longtodate(max(srm.Responsetime)) AS "Survey responded Time", max(srcmt.COMMENTTEXT) AS "Comments",max(srm.result) "Over All Satisfaction Level" FROM SurveyResponseRequestMapping srrm 
INNER JOIN Survey_Response_Main srm ON srrm.RESPONSEID=srm.RESPONSEID 
INNER JOIN Survey_Response_Answer sra ON srm.RESPONSEID=sra.RESPONSEID 
LEFT JOIN Survey_Response_Comment srcmt ON srm.RESPONSEID=srcmt.RESPONSEID 
LEFT JOIN WorkOrder wo ON srrm.WORKORDERID=wo.WORKORDERID 
LEFT JOIN WorkOrderStates wos ON wo.WORKORDERID=wos.WORKORDERID 
LEFT JOIN SDUser td ON wos.OWNERID=td.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser ti ON td.USERID=ti.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdu ON wo.REQUESTERID=sdu.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aau ON sdu.USERID=aau.USER_ID 
INNER JOIN AccountSiteMapping asm ON wo.siteid=asm.siteid 
INNER JOIN AccountDefinition ad ON asm.accountid=ad.org_id
left join aaausercontactinfo auci on auci.user_id = sdu.userid 
left join aaacontactinfo aci on aci.contactinfo_id = auci.contactinfo_id
where srm.RESPONSETIME>=DATETOLONG('2021-03-22 00:00:00') and srm.RESPONSETIME<=DATETOLONG('2021-03-31 23:59:59')
GROUP BY wo.WORKORDERID order by 7
```

My question is if can I run this raw SQL statement inside my .NET core console application and map the returned columns into C# variables?

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: @Hayden thanks for the reply.. have not use it before.. is it similar to EF core?

Comment: It's a micro-orm that can allow you to execute a raw query and map to an object.

Comment: @Hayden ok i see i read the documentation,, but it is somehow poor.. it does not fully explain how we can map the columns into c# variables

Comment: Simple.  Use an Adatper and put data into a DataTable.  Each column is equivalent to a variable.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Not sure how to map an sql query to a single value variable unless the query itself is scalar. Cleanest approach is to map the query to either a datatable or to a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) for run **Raw SQL** code and set value to class

### Example

`var data = await connection.QueryAsync<YourClass>(sql, parameters);`

> Note: you can create new class then create property like your query **must some (Name and Datatype)**